# Where to put custom exception classes in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Where do I put custom exception classes in a Rails 5 (api) project now that `lib/` seems to essentially be deprecated? Specifically I'm looking to extend ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound with some custom behavior.

Comment: Nothing wrong with putting it in `lib` if that's what you're used to. Or a subfolder of `app`, it's really just a personal choice.

Comment: I would name space it either under `ApplicationRecord` or some other namespace if there is a more logical one.